# What is the difference in this way of method calling

Tags: php, oop

As I got it, in the first example an object is created, and in the second one I don't see an object created. I am trying to understand, what is the difference between the two ways of method calling :

```
<?php

class Animal{

    public $voice;

    public function speak($sound){
        echo $this->voice = $sound;
    }

}

// Example 1

$tiger = new Animal();
$tiger->speak('Roar');

// Example 2

(new Animal)->speak("Cloak Cloak");
```

Comment: object created in second one also?

Comment: I am myself confused. :-D

Comment: object and reference to object are two different things. See difference between them you will understand what makes you confused

Comment: ok, thanks MstfAsan will check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you are assigning the variable $tiger as a new Object, by which you can then call the functions and variables associated with that object, by referencing $tiger.

i.e. as Tiger now equals an Object of Class Animal, it can speak.

However in the second example, you are still creating a new Object of class Animal, and as such it can speak - but you have not assigned it to a variable. So you cannot reference that same Object any longer.

So in the first example, if we wanted to name our $tiger, we could have the Class look something like this.

```
class Animal{

public $voice;
public $name = "I have no name."; 

public function speak($sound){
    echo $this->voice = $sound;
    }

public function sayYourName(){
   echo $this->name;
    }

}
```

Now if we say,

```
$tiger = new Animal();
$tiger->speak('Roar');
$tiger->name = "Rory";
$tiger->sayYourName(); // This will echo "Rory"
```

However, if you try your second example instead :

```
(new Animal)->sayYourName(); // This will echo "I have no name."
```

So if you say :

```
 (new Animal)->name = "Rory";
 (new Animal)->sayYourName(); // This will still echo "I have no name".
```

This is because we haven't assigned a reference to the new animal, so while we can access methods of the function, and even predefined variables, we can't then reference them again later on.

To do that, we should stick to the first method (i.e. referencing)

```
$tiger = new Animal();
$tiger->name = "Rory";
$tiger->sayYourName();
```

In conclusion, use referencing to refer to an Object later on. i.e to get the animals attention, you have to call it by its name.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use "new", you're creating an instance of an object (it can be temporary). The difference in your code is that in the first example, you're storing the instance in "$tiger", so it'll persist, but in the second example you're only instantiating a temporary object to call a method.

Comment: Ok..so can you tell which one is more preferable and why ?

Comment: If you don't need to save the "$tiger" instance to perform more operations, the second example will be better since you're not reserving memory for storing the object. However, if you need "$tiger" to store information and call some methods above that, you should store it in a variable.
As @MstfAsan said, check the difference between objects and references, since they're pillars of OOP.